# Changing size of diagram when using diagxy package?

Tags: diagrams, diagxy

Can we change size of diagram when using diagxy package? If not, is there better package for diagram in category theory.

For example, I want to increase size of the following diagram

```
$$\bfig
\square[A`B`C`D;e`f`g`m]
\efig$$
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please make an example of the diagram you want to draw? Indeed, there are better packages, nowadays.

Comment: @egreg, check my edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems that `tikz-cd` is better suited to your needs. for example:

```
    \documentclass[margin=3.1415692mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz-cd}

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=huge,row sep=huge]% here you can define diagram size, font size etc
A   \ar{r}{e}
    \ar{d}{f}   &   B   \ar{d}{g}   \\
C   \ar{r}{m}   &   D
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using `tikz-cd`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=2em,row sep=2em]
A \arrow[r,"e"] \arrow[d,swap,"f"] & B \arrow[d,"g"] \\
C \arrow[r,swap,"m"] & D
\end{tikzcd}
\qquad
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=4em,row sep=4em]
A \arrow[r,"e"] \arrow[d,swap,"f"] & B \arrow[d,"g"] \\
C \arrow[r,swap,"m"] & D
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

The `swap` key imposes that the arrow label is set to the opposite side (default is on the left, imagining to look from the source towards the target).

[image]

Alternatively, use directly Xy-pic.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}

\[
\xymatrix{
  A \ar[r]^e \ar[d]_f & B \ar[d]^g \\
  C \ar[r]_m & D
}
\qquad
\xymatrix@R+2pc@C+2pc{
  A \ar[r]^e \ar[d]_f & B \ar[d]^g \\
  C \ar[r]_m & D
}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]